# Controller Laravel, filter data user Auth Table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model-view-controller, bootstrap-4

In MySQL I have several user data, I need to filter the data automatically with the user who logged into the system. Below is a part of the code in the controller:

```
        //executa a query
        $lista = Ponto::with('name')->where('name', Auth::name() )
        ->get();
```

(MySql) Table ponto / structure:

```
id  
name    
cpf 
cargo   
data_inicial    
hora_inicial    
ref_hora_inicial    
ref_hora_final  
data_final  
hora_final  
created_at  
updated_at  



28
Arecelino Soares
012.213.564-80
Motorista
2021-11-18
16:22
17:12
17:12
2021-11-30
22:30
2021-11-09 19:23:55
2021-11-16 12:34:30



77
Robison Santos
132.321.432-43
Motorista
2021-11-16
12:57
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
2021-11-16 15:55:09
2021-11-16 15:55:09
```

complement: Table Laravel, Users data

[image: complement: Table Laravel, Users data]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it this way but it no longer filters the dates in the form?

$lista = Ponto::where('name', Auth::user()->name)->get();

```
public function dados(Request $request)
{

    if ($request->input('data_inicial')) {
        $data['data_inicial'] = $request->input('data_inicial');
        $request->session()->put('data_inicial', $request->input('data_inicial'));
    } elseif ($request->session()->has('data_inicial')) {
        $data['data_inicial'] = $request->session()->get('data_inicial');
    } else {
        $data['data_inicial'] = null;
    }

    if ($request->input('geral')) {
        $request->session()->forget('data_inicial');
        $data['data'] = null;
    }

        $date = $data['data_inicial'];
        $lista = Ponto::
        when($date, function ($query, $date) {
            return $query->where('data_inicial', $date);
        })
       
        ->orderBy('data_inicial', 'DESC')->get();
        $lista = Ponto::where('name', Auth::user()->name)->get();
                    
        $data['lista'] = $lista;
        foreach ($lista as $item) {
            if ($item->data_inicial) {
                $dd = explode("-", $item->data_inicial);
                $ddc = $dd[2] . "/" . $dd[1] . "/" . $dd[0];
                $item->data_inicial = $ddc;
            }

        if ($item->data_final) {
            $dd = explode("-", $item->data_final);
            $ddc = $dd[2] . "/" . $dd[1] . "/" . $dd[0];
            $item->data_final = $ddc;
        }
}

    return view('dados', $data);
}
```